# Independently scrolling divs, one with fixed header & footer

Tags: html, css

I have two independently scrolling divs, one with a header and footer.

```
<body>
  <div class="container col-1">
    Many listings
  </div>
  <div class="container col-2">
    <div class="header">Fixed Header</div>
    <div class="content">Lots of content</div>
    <div class="footer">Fixed footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhmvv05n/

The problem is, I'd like the second container div to have a fixed header and footer that are always visible and have only the content scrollable.

As soon as I change the scrolling of the `col-2` div, the two columns don't scroll independently anymore.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will adjust to whatever `width` you have for your columns.
The idea is that you only make `.col-2.content` scrollable, not the whole `.container`.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-1{
  float: left;
  width: 33%; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.col-2{
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
  position: relative;
}

.col-2 .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 20px; /* header height */
  bottom: 20px; /* footer height */
  overflow: auto;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

.header {
  top: 0;  
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could something like this work for you?

https://jsfiddle.net/vz7eb8uc/

Code changed;

```
.col-1{
  float: left;
  width: 33%; 
    position: relative;

}
.col-2{
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
  position: relative;
}
.header, .footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 33%;
  width:67%
}
```